# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'

Tags: python

I have a custom module have written and i am having trouble installing. Here is the structure of the module.

```
├── my_module
│   ├── .git
│   │   ├── <..>
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── <..>
│   ├── class_a
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── class_a_name.py
│   ├── class_b
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── class_b_name.py
│   ├── dist
│   │   ├── <..>
│   ├── my_module.egg.info
│   │   ├── <..>
│   ├── setup.py
│       ├── .gitignore
```

This is stored within `C:\Users\my_name\repos\my_module`.

To install the module I run `setup.py` with the command `python setup.py install` in the anaconda prompt.

When this is run if i navigate to `C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\my_module-0.2-py3.7.egg`

the .egg file exists and it appears as if my module has been installed.

However when i try to use the module in spyder or through the command prompt i get:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'`

I don't think this is a path issue like a lot of the other questions on the topic.

Thanks in advance, happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a path issue. (and yes, setting up the paths proper is really annoying)

Proper path for imports would look like:

```py
├── my_module
│   ├── .git
│   │   ├── <..>
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── <..>
│   │   my_module         <-- NEW
│   │   ├── __init__.py   <-- NEW
│   │   ├── class_a
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── class_a_name.py
│   │   ├── class_b
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── class_b_name.py
│   ├── dist
│   │   ├── <..>
│   ├── my_module.egg.info
│   │   ├── <..>
│   ├── setup.py
```

Note that this would exclude `build` and `dist` from the actual installation of your module. Move them up to if you don't want that.

This can perhaps be accomplished by moving setup.py outwards instead of creating a new folder, but that's up to you.

Comment: Yes that worked. You have saved me from another 3 hours of frustration. Many thanks :)

Comment: Glad that my 3 hours of frustration last year can prevent yours now :)